# Capital Ø (Scandinavian letter) in Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, characters, scandinavian-letters

I know that I can preserve capital letters in Bibtex with curly braces, and that I can type Scandinavian letters like æøå as `\ae{}` `\o{}` `\aa{}`. But what do I do to force the capital letters ÆØÅ? Following a suggestion I found for German umlaut, I tried `{\{O}}`, but it still comes out as a lowercase ø.

Bibtex file:

```
@misc{o2012,
    title = "This is the word \O{}re"}
```

Latex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{o2012}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try

```
@misc{o2012,
    title = {This is the word {{\O}}re},
    ...
```

Comment: That works. Since it has fewer curly braces that Joseph's answer, I choose this as the better one. Thanks.

Comment: The second or outer pair of curly braces is needed because the `plain` bibliography style uses "sentence style" for the contents of `title` fields for entries of type `@misc`. "Sentence style" means that everything except the first word of the field is converted to lowercase. The outer pair of curly braces informs BibTeX *not* to convert to lowercase what's *inside* thosee curly braces. If the entry type were `@book` or `@inbook`, say, the outer pair of curly braces would not be needed -- since "title style" is applied to the `title` fields of latter two entry types.

Answer (score 5):

My usual rule is 'try more braces' in cases like this. For me

```
@misc{o2012,
    title = "This is the word {{\O{}}}re"
}
```

seems to work fine.